# discord.py: Trying to wait for author response and answer it

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently trying to make a bot using discord.py, and I have a small problem: I don't know how to wait for the author response and for the bot to post another message after it.
Here's my code for the moment:

````
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('.pdfcheckup'):
        await message.channel.send("Quelle matière scolaire cherchez-vous ?\nListe des matières disponibles:\n**```\n1- Histoire\n2- Géographie\n3- EMC\n4- Français\n6- Mathématiques\n7- Physique-Chimie\n8- Enseignement Scientifique\n9- NSI\n10- Anglais\n11- Espagnol\n12- Allemand\n```**")

client.run('[my token]')
````

So, to sum what my bot needs to do, the author writes ".pdfcheckup", the bot responds with the long message, the bot waits for the author to say a number between 1 and 12, and depending on the number the author picked, it answers with a special message. But I'm dumb to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for):

```py
def author_check(author):
    return lambda message: message.author == author

# later in your code
await message.channel.send("long message")
msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=author_check(message.author), timeout=30.0)
print(msg.content) # will be whatever the original author sent
```

The `timeout` parameter is just the maximum time, in seconds, to wait for the event to happen.